# Leaflet Zoom Map Layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am looking function which enable me to loss of parts of Layer when zooming the map.

```
map.on('zoomend', onZoomend)
function onZoomend(feature){
if(map.getZoom()<11) 
 {map.addLayer("road_2"==feature.properties.density)};

if(map.getZoom()>11)
 {map.removeLayer("road_2"==feature.properties.density)};
  }
```

My GeoJson file is in panel layers:

```
var overLayers = [
{
    group: "Layer",
    collapsed: true,
    layers: [
        {   
            name: "Road",
            icon: iconByName('fuel_road'),              
            layer: L.geoJson(road,{style: style_road})
        },
```

File GeoJson bulid that:

```
      var road = {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",

    "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "density" : "road_1"....

    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "density" : "road_2"....

    { "type": "Feature", "properties": ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you right, but you want to remove a layer when zooming in and adding it when zooming out?

```
You just can use:
if(map.getZoom()<11){
    mylayer.removeFrom(map);
}else{    
    mylayer.addTo(map);
}
```

Did I understand you right?

UPDATE:

You can iterate through the GeoJson Layer and set the fillOpacity to 0 for hiding some geoms:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(myGeoJson).addTo(map);
if(map.getZoom()<11){
 geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
   if(layer.feature.properties.density == "road_"){
       layer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0});
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: Well you understood, but this layer is placed in the file GeoJSON. I want to turn off the portion of the file, eg. A number of polygons that will not be visible at high zoom.

Comment: Then create `L.LayerGroup`s with the groups of leaflet layers you want to add/remove from the map, add the individual layers to those groups (probably through `L.GeoJSON`'s `eachLayer`), then add/remove those groups as needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Is this way have a future? What must it be improved?

```
 function style_road(feature) {
    if  ("road_1" == feature.properties.density) {
        return {
            weight: 3,
            opacity:function()
                    {if (zoom > 13) {opacity:0},
                    else (zoom < 13) {opacity:1}, 
                    },
            color: 'red',
        };
    } 
    else if ("road_2" == feature.properties.density){
        return {
            weight: 1.5,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'red',               
        };
    }
    else {
        return {
            weight: 0.5,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'red',               
        };
    }
}
```